# Biblatex: no comma between title and year with citation that has no author

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I've researched this problem, but am not coming up with the right solution.  I have a online resource with no author, so with APA style, biblatex produces: ("Title of article" 2009} with no comma. But the style requires a comma in between the title and the year.  I think I need something along the lines of:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}}
```

But it is not working.

```
Here is a minimal example:

\documentclass[man,]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
%\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
%\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}}


\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}

\author{Tom  }
\affiliation{University of Ignorance}

\date{May 28, 2017}

\abstract{This paper is meant to illustrate a problem I have with Latex     
}
\keywords{ignorance}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
I want to cite this \citep{vicodin}.  


\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered] 


\end{document}
```

The minimal bib file (example.bib) would be this:

```
@Online{vicodin,
  title = {Life Without Vicodin?},
  year  = {2009},
  date  = {2009-07-02},
  url   = {http://nymag.com/news/intelligencer/topic/57770/},
}
```

Note: when I reproduce the error in the minimal example above, I notice that the reference occurs correctly in the reference listing at the end, but it still has no comma in the inline citation.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted the comma for everything,

```
\renewcommand*{\nonameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

would be enough. You don't need the `\AtBeginBibliography` hook.

But you don't actually need that here, the citation macros of `biblatex-apa` use `\nameyeardelim`, which is set to `\addcomma\space` in `apa.cbx`.

Your problem here is different, though.

---

You are not seeing the comma because of US punctuation and the question mark that ends the title.

With `american` (American English) `biblatex` uses `\uspunctuation`, this involves moving punctuation inside quotation marks. So you have

> "Carefree," in general, means "free from care or anxiety."

and not (British style/'logical' punctuation)

> "Carefree", in general, means "free from care or anxiety".

This is also what happens here. The comma is moved inside the quotation mark. Instead of (British)

> "Life Without Vicodin?", 2009

you would have (American)

> *"Life Without Vicodin?," 2009

but that double punctuation is not acceptable and the quotation mark wins (it is more important), so you get
you would have

> "Life Without Vicodin?" 2009

Try dropping the question mark in the title and check the output.

If you don't want US punctuation, issue

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{\stdpunctuation}
```

Comment: Thank you @moewe.   **\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{\stdpunctuation}** did the trick.  I really appreciate your help.  When looking on this type of thing earlier, your name came up often.  Thanks for your generosity in helping others.

Comment: @T.Frei Keep in mind that `\stdpunctuation` switches citations and bibliography to British/logical punctuation, i.e. you will get the punctuation outside the quotation marks. I'm not sure what the APA exactly prescribe, but they want American punctuation (http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/08/punctuating-around-quotation-marks.html). So your document will not be APA compliant if you go for `\stdpunctuation`.

Comment: @T.Frei Glad my answer helped you. You might want to consider up-voting and accepting it to show that it solved your problem.